# Why messsage comes to queue but not handles? It used to work before. Does nservicebus requires a registration?

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

For some reason for azure service bus my nservicebus stopped working:
public class ConfigureLogging : IWantCustomLogging
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            Configure.Instance.ConsoleLogger();
        }
    }

```
class DefineRouting : IProvideConfiguration<UnicastBusConfig>
{
    public UnicastBusConfig GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new UnicastBusConfig
        {
            MessageEndpointMappings = new MessageEndpointMappingCollection
            {
                new MessageEndpointMapping { Messages="ServiceBus.Messages", Endpoint="webinputqueue" }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class EndpointConfiguration : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Worker, UsingTransport<AzureServiceBus>
{
    public EndpointConfiguration()
    {
        Feature.Disable<SecondLevelRetries>();
        Feature.Disable<TimeoutManager>();
    }
}
```

public class Host : NServiceBus.Hosting.Azure.RoleEntryPoint
    {
        private IScheduler scheduler;

```
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        RegisterByObjectFactory.Register();

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

In app config I have proper settings:

Version of NServiceBus is: 4.1

Azure config settings:

```
AzureServiceBusQueueConfig.QueueName: webinputqueue
MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig.ErrorQueue: errorqueue 
AzureProfileConfig.Profiles: NServiceBus.Development 
TransportConfig.MaxRetries: 5 
TransportConfig.MaximumConcurrencyLevel: 1
```

The GoogleCalendarHandler looks like this:

```
public class GoogleCalendarHandler : IHandleMessages<GoogleCalendarCommand>
    {

        public void Handle(GoogleCalendarCommand message)
        {
            Operate(message);
        }
...
```

Comment: Can it be because I need some licence file to put inside the package or something? Or maybe some port is not allwed? But I didn't change nothing and it worked before. Please help

Comment: I see nothing wrong at first sight, do you see anything weird in the debug output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that I missed licence file! But the system didn't inform me that my trial is end.
http://particular.net/licensing I donwloaded the license file and it started working.